# emulator does not show secondActivity

Tags: android

I have written program in android. Emulator does not show the second activity soon after clicking on the main activity. Please, can any one guide me. thanks in advance.

MainActivity.java

```
btnNext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Bundle b = new Bundle();

            // Creating Intent object
            Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
            b.putIntArray("condition", conditions);
            b.putStringArray("day", days);

            // Storing bundle object into intent
            in.putExtras(b);
            startActivity(in);      
        }

    });
```

SecondActivity.java

public class SecondActivity extends Activity {

```
int conditions[];
String days[];


//Button ImageView Initialization
Button btnPrevious =  null;
Button btnNext =  null;

// days initialization together with declaration 
TextView T1DayTitle = null;
TextView T2DayTitle = null;
TextView T3DayTitle = null;
TextView T4DayTitle = null;

// weather image initialization together with declaration 
ImageView T2C4R5 = null;
ImageView T4C4R1 = null;
ImageView T3C4R1 = null;
ImageView T1C4R4 = null;

// dress image initialization together with declaration
ImageView T1C4R1 = null;
ImageView T1C2R3 = null;
ImageView T1C1R4 = null;

ImageView T2C4R1 = null;
ImageView T2C2R3 = null;
ImageView T2C1R5 = null;

ImageView T4C1R1 = null;
ImageView T4C2R2 = null;
ImageView T4C5R5 = null;

ImageView T3C4R5 = null;
ImageView T3C2R3 = null;
ImageView T3C1R1 = null;

//
ImageView[][] dressImageView = new ImageView[4][3];

ImageView [] wImage = new ImageView[4];

//
TextView[] day = new TextView[4];

TextView txtTest = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.second_activity);

    //Button ImageView Initialization
    Button btnPrevious =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPrevious2);
    Button btnNext =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNext2);



    // days initialization together with declaration 
    T1DayTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.T1DayTitle);
    T2DayTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.T2DayTitle);
    T3DayTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.T3DayTitle);
    T4DayTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.T4DayTitle);

    // weather image initialization together with declaration 
    T2C4R5 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.T2C4R5);
    T4C4R1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.T4C4R1);
    T3C4R1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.T3C4R1);
    T1C4R4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.T1C4R4);

    // dress image initialization together with declaration
    T1C4R1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.T1C4R1); 
    T1C2R3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.T1C2R3);
    T1C1R4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.T1C1R4);

    T2C4R1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.T2C4R1);
    T2C2R3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.T2C2R3);
    T2C1R5 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.T2C1R5);

    T4C1R1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.T4C1R1);
    T4C2R2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.T4C2R2);
    T4C5R5 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.T4C5R5);

    T3C4R5 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.T3C4R5);
    T3C2R3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.T3C2R3);
    T3C1R1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.T3C1R1);

//  txtTest = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtTest2);


    dressImageView = new ImageView[][] {
        {T1C4R1, T1C2R3, T1C1R4},
        {T2C4R1,T2C2R3, T2C1R5} ,
        {T3C4R5, T3C2R3, T3C1R1},
        {T4C1R1, T4C2R2,T4C5R5} }; 

    wImage = new ImageView[] {T1C4R4 ,T2C4R5, T4C4R1, T3C4R1 };
    day = new TextView[] {T1DayTitle, T2DayTitle, T3DayTitle, T4DayTitle}; 
//

    // get the Intent that started this Activity
    Intent in = getIntent();

    // get the Bundle that stores the data of this Activity
    Bundle b = in.getExtras();

    // getting data from bundle
    conditions = b.getIntArray("condition");
    days = b.getStringArray("day");

    //txtTest.setText(conditions[0] + ", " + conditions[1] + ", " + conditions[2] + ", " + conditions[3] + ", " + days[0]);
    // 

    for (int c = 0; c < conditions.length; c++) {
        day[c].setText(days[c]);

        displayWeather(c, conditions[c] );
        Log.d("TAG", "Index " + c + "Condtion Image" + conditions[c]);
        //displayDress(c, conditions[c]);
    }

    btnPrevious.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Creating Intent object
            Intent in = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, MainActivity.class);

            startActivity(in);
        }
    });

    btnNext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Bundle b = new Bundle();

    b.putIntArray("condition", conditions);
            b.putStringArray("day", days);


            // Creating Intent object
            Intent in = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, DetailActivity.class);

            // Storing bundle object into intent
            in.putExtras(b);
            startActivity(in);
        }
    });
}
private void dayWeatherCondtionImage(int index, String day,ImageView[] dayCell) {
    dayCell[index].setImageDrawable(getDrawableByName(SecondActivity.this, day));
}
private void displayWeather(int day, int condition) {
    //String name = "condition_" + condition;
    String name = ConditionConverter.condition_map.get(condition);
    wImage[day].setImageDrawable(getDrawableByName(SecondActivity.this, name));
}
//
public Drawable getDrawableByName(Context context, String name){
    Resources resources = getResources();
    final int resourceId = resources.getIdentifier(name, "drawable", context.getPackageName());
    return resources.getDrawable(resourceId);
}
```

Comment: You should share more informations. Are ther any error messages? How looks your Layoutfile?

Answer (score 0):

There could be many reasons why SecondActivity is not showing.  Have you already declared SecondActivity in your Manifest file? Have you tried clicking on the Next button?  Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: yes.                                                                                                    manifest.xml :                                                                                                                            <activity 
            android:name=".SecondActivity" 
            android:label="@string/app_name">
        </activity>

Comment: Please, could you explain what kind of error messages.

Comment: check my original code. I have added SecondActivity.java code.